# I'm Getting Error with Gradlew bundle in Ionic 5

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle, build.gradle

I'm trying to compile Ionic v 5 to `.aab` using `gradlew bundle` but I'm getting error message.
I'm able to use `ionic cordova build android` and `ionic cordova build android --prod --release` but since Google console only accept .aab, I used gradle but It is not working.
Below is the Error Message

```
> Configure project :CordovaLib
publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All variants are now published.

> Configure project :app
Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
+-----------------------------------------------------------------
| cordova-android-support-gradle-release: 27.+
+-----------------------------------------------------------------
The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
        at build_cnc5naln5i7uh2x22c0faw97o.run(C:\Users\App Source Code\Kun Fat\platforms\android\app\build.gradle:151)


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'bundle' is ambiguous in root project 'android'. Candidates are: 'bundleAppClassesDebug', 'bundleAppClassesDebugAndroidTest', 'bundleAppClassesDebugUnitTest', 'bundleAppClassesRelease', 'bundleAppClassesReleaseUnitTest', 'bundleDebug', 'bundleRelease'.

* Try:
Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

I tired to use gradlew bundleRelease which build successful BUT no .aab was generated.
HOW CAN I GENERATE .aab from Ionic using gradle.
BELOW IS MY IONIC INFO

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.2.3 (C:\Users\olade\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.10
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.24
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.0.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 7.1.4
   Cordova Plugins   : not available

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : 0.2.8

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\olade\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v12.16.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.13.1
   OS                : Windows 10
```

Comment: do you use android studio 3?

Comment: No I'm using CMD. When I import to Android Studio, it give error below. ERROR: Could not find method leftShift() for arguments [build_cnc5naln5i7uh2x22c0faw97o$_run_closure6@4be7e9ab] on task ':app:cdvPrintProps' of type org.gradle.api.DefaultTask.

Comment: What is your gradle version (in cmd type gradle --v)

Comment: Gradle 5.1.1 ....... 
Build time:   2019-01-10 23:05:02 UTC
Revision:     3c9abb645fb83932c44e8610642393ad62116807

Kotlin DSL:   1.1.1
Kotlin:       1.3.11
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018
JVM:          1.8.0_211 (Oracle Corporation 25.211-b12)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64

Comment: Update you gradle to the latest which is 6.+ check gradle.org/install and download the latest version and make steps to declare it, and then retry to build gradlew again after you update it.

Comment: Did updating gradle work for you?

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same problem. The solution was updating to android@8.
Here is some more detail on how to do this:

list your platforms with:

```
ionic cordova platform list
```

remove android with:

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
```

add android@8:

```
ionic cordova platform add android@8
```

run the command:

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

and then:

```
gradlew bundle
```